# Position an image with Swift and CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, draw

I'm working on a drawing app using Swift and it's my first time using CoreGraphics. My app is a drawing with two steps:

1. Drawing then pass the image to a UICollectionView
2. Take the image from the UICollectionView **and draw above it**.

What I need to know is how to position the image at the bottom of the hierarchy. Here's an example of my code, which positions the image in the center:

```
import UIKit

class TheViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var drawingPlace: UIImageView!
  var theFisrtImageFromStep1 = arrayOfPlans[choseOne]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    drawingPlace.image = theFisrtImageFromStep1
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you i will try to focus in the way i explain and learn more english .

Comment: Don't forget to call super.viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solve my problem** :

```
func resize(collectionImage : UIImage) -> UIImage{
        let point = CGPoint(x: drawingPlace.frame.width / 4, y: drawingPlace.frame.height - 300)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingPlace.frame.size)
        collectionImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin:  point , size: CGSize(width: drawingPlace.frame.size.width / 2, height: drawingPlace.frame.size.height / 2)))

        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return img!
    }
```

in viewDidLoad :

```
drawingPlace.image = resize(collectionImage: arrayOfPlans[choseOne])
```

this function : resize my image , position the image in the bottom and thats what i need , thank you .